# Joining meshes - how to deal with remapping of the textures?

Tags: uv, texture-coordinates

I have a model (from external source). It has a large number of meshes, which I don't need and would just clump the whole thing.

So I'd like to reduce the number by joining some of the meshes, specifically ones that will be immovable and share a texture file. But when I do it just with Ctrl-J, it messes up the texture  - I guess it messes up the UV map, hence the texture mapping.

To be clear, I want to join ONLY meshes that already share a texture file, and have a UV map on that file.

Is there some reasonable way to do this automagically? To do it manually would not be much different than leaving the multiplicity of meshes alone.

Comment: It doesn't mess with the UV map, you probably have materials based on object or generated coordinate system, and that's the problem. [How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3050/60486)

Comment: Can't use BSE due to copyright, but I figured it out, I just needed to rename UV maps on the meshes to the same name.

Comment: For future questions: you can (and should, regardless of copyrights!) minimize your problem by stripping it away of stuff that is copyrightable.

Answer (score 2):

When joining the meshes which refer to the same image picture, to keep the texture correct the meshes UV maps must have the same name.